# OpenLayers.Layer.WMS and mapserver

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver

I have a problem when I add a OpenLayers.Layer.WMS, I get a picture of my map but I can't do zoom on it. I read a lot of questions here but nothing help me. My MapServer map file is:

```
MAP
 ##CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/ms4w/tmp/ms_error.txt"
 ##DEBUG 2
 ##CONFIG "CPL_DEBUG" "ON"
 NAME mapa2
 SIZE 1400 900
 IMAGETYPE png
 IMAGECOLOR 196 240 255
 EXTENT -16.1737 27.6847 -13.1254 29.4506
 SHAPEPATH "datos"
 FONTSET "C:/../fonts.txt"
 WEB 
      TEMPLATE "/../index.html"
      IMAGEPATH "/../ms_tmp/"
      IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
      METADATA
         "WMS_TITLE" mapa2
         "WMS_SRS" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:4258"
         "WMS_ONLINERESOURCE" "../mapa2.map"
         "WMS_ENABLE_REQUEST" "*"
      END
 END
 PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4258"
 END
 UNITS DD
 #FOTOS AEREAS
 LAYER
    NAME Foto1
    TILEINDEX indice.shp
    TILEITEM location
    DATA Foto1
    TYPE RASTER
    STATUS on
    OFFSITE 252 252 252 
    METADATA
        WMS_NAME "Foto1"
        WMS_FORMAT "IMAGE/PNG"
        WMS_SRS "EPSG:4258"
    END
 END
 LAYER
    NAME    "MUNICIPIO"
    STATUS  ON
    DATA    MUNICIPIO
    LABELITEM "NOM_MUNICI"
    METADATA
        "WMS_TITLE" MUNICIPIO
    END
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4258"
    END
    TYPE POLYGON
    CLASS
        STYLE
            COLOR 254 226 197
            OUTLINECOLOR    255 0 0
        END
        LABEL 
            SIZE SMALL
            COLOR 0 0 0
            ALIGN CENTER
            REPEATDISTANCE 9
            POSITION CC
        END
    END
 END
END
```

And I try to add the layer:

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
  'Municipios', 
  "../mapa2.map&service=wms&mode=map&request=getcapabilities",  
  {layers:"MUNICIPIO"},{
   isBaseLayer:"true",
   srs: "EPSG:4258",
  format: 'image/png',
  visibility: "true",
  transparent: "true", 
  singleTile: true,
  ratio: 1 });
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: I guess that mode=map can make troubles. It is either-or with WMS and mode=map.

Comment: I have the same problem using only one of them.

Comment: Do you know that if your Mapserver is new enough it has OpenLayers as an outputformat? It creates a simple viewer when you use &format=application/openlayers and by looking at the source code you can see a working example. Try http://188.64.1.61/cgi-bin/ms_ows?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=353&LAYERS=sea&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=application/openlayers&BBOX=-159106.5127115796,6813112.750612677,939497.2664934493,7658008.467517634&SRS=EPSG:3067&STYLES=

Comment: OpenLayers is a library, I only call to the mapserver to request a wms.

Comment: Yes, but because it looks like you have used wrong code when trying to add Mapserver WMS into your application I suggested to have a look how it has been done in a working application. I do not master OpenLayers myself, I am sorry.

Comment: No problem, if I fix it, I post the solution.

Comment: The simple viewer has it like this `var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
{maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-157909.776569,6814309.486756,938300.530351,7656811.731375),
maxResolution: 2393.472286});
var mslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('MapServer Simple Viewer',
'http://188.64.1.61/cgi-bin/ms_ows?',
{layers: 'sea',
bbox: '-157909.776569,6814309.486756,938300.530351,7656811.731375',
width: 459, height: 353, version: '1.1.1', format:'image/svg+xml'},                                   {singleTile: "true", ratio:1, projection: 'EPSG:3067'});
;`

Comment: It doesn't work, its like the map doesn't load.

Comment: It was a problem with the path only putting wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('Municipios', "../mapa2.map was fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
  'Municipios',"../mapa2.map&service=wms&mode=map&request=getcapabilities",
```

This line is incorrect.  You need to use the service end point only so it should be something like:

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
  'Municipios',"http://yourservice/mapserv.exe?map=mapa2.map&",
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the control OpenLayers.Control.Navigation() to the OpenLayers.Map object. Please check this: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.8/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control-js.html
Hope it helps if you haven´t found the solution already.